# How to complete group in resequencer from spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I use [resequencer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#resequencer) to ensure correct order of messages. When some process with multiple messages ends I would like to launch the same process with the same correlation id once more. It does not working because message group for particular correlation id is not completed and still exists for resequencer so there is no message to release (all messages are replayed from beginning thus no message with greater sequence number then last one from the first process is ever received). For [aggregator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#aggregator) it is possible to set `expire-groups-upon-completion` property but it seems there is no such functionality for [resequencer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#resequencer). Is it possible to obtain described functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, unlike the aggregator, there is no concept of "completion" from the resequencer's perspective - it has no way to know that the group is "complete".

That's the reason why it's not available as an option on the resequencer itself.

You can provide an external `MessageGroupStore` bean - the resequencer creates it's own `SimpleMessageStore` internally by default, but you can provide a reference your own bean.

Then, when you know the group is "complete", you can call `removeMessageGroup()` with the correlation ID, and that will reset the resequencer.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I can imagine some examples of "completion" like sequence size or expression applied to message (e.g. for some header). Fortunately there is workaround for lack of this functionality so I will try now to implement your suggestion.